# Download many images to listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am writing Windows Phone application and can't understand why the emulator crashes. It says that: "Unhandled exception at `0x773415de` in XDE.exe: `0xC0000005`: Access violation reading location `0x05190000`." This problem appears only when I begin to scroll very fast my listbox. I load per 20 items to listbox (the number of all items is 200). The problem is in my class of downloading images. I create a Webclient request for each image to server or it's better to create a thread pool?

In XAML:

```
<Image Name="userPic" Margin="0,8,1,2"
                            DelayFix:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding photoUrl}" Stretch="Fill"
                            Width="60"
                            Height="60"/>
```

downloadImage class:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PhoneApp
{
    public class downloadImage
    {
        public int ImageIndex;

        public string ImageURL;

        public Boolean Downloaded;


        public BitmapImage Bitmap;

        public Image destinationImage; 

        private WebClient client;

        public delegate void FileCompleteHandler(object sender);
        public event FileCompleteHandler FileCompleteEvent;

        private static readonly object _syncBlock = new object();

        public downloadImage(int index, string imageURL, Image destinationImage = null)
        {
            this.ImageIndex = index;
            this.ImageURL = imageURL;
            this.destinationImage = destinationImage;
        }

        public void Download()
        {
            client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(this.ImageURL, UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        StreamResourceInfo sri = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result as Stream, null);


                        if (destinationImage == null)
                        {
                            this.Bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                            this.Bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.destinationImage.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.Result);
                        }

                        this.Downloaded = true;

                        if (FileCompleteEvent != null)
                            FileCompleteEvent(this);      
                    }));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The code of my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Phone;
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;

namespace DelayFix
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to the Image.UriSource attached property which allows
    /// Images to be loaded by Windows Phone with less impact to the UI thread.
    /// </summary>
    public static class LowProfileImageLoader
    {
        private static readonly object _syncBlock = new object();
        private static bool _exiting;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the Uri to use for providing the contents of the Image's Source property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Image needing its Source property set.</param>
        /// <returns>Uri to use for providing the contents of the Source property.</returns>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1011:ConsiderPassingBaseTypesAsParameters", Justification = "UriSource is applicable only to Image elements.")]
        public static Uri GetUriSource(Image obj)
        {
            if (null == obj)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            }
            return (Uri)obj.GetValue(UriSourceProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the Uri to use for providing the contents of the Image's Source property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Image needing its Source property set.</param>
        /// <param name="value">Uri to use for providing the contents of the Source property.</param>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1011:ConsiderPassingBaseTypesAsParameters", Justification = "UriSource is applicable only to Image elements.")]
        public static void SetUriSource(Image obj, Uri value)
        {
            if (null == obj)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            }
            obj.SetValue(UriSourceProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the UriSource attached DependencyProperty.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UriSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "UriSource", typeof(Uri), typeof(LowProfileImageLoader), new PropertyMetadata(OnUriSourceChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether low-profile image loading is enabled.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1810:InitializeReferenceTypeStaticFieldsInline", Justification = "Static constructor performs additional tasks.")]
        static LowProfileImageLoader()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Limit Memory:" + DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit / 1024 / 1024);
        }

        private static void HandleApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exit!");
        }



        private static void OnUriSourceChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (_syncBlock)
            {
                var image = (Image)o;
                var uri = (Uri)e.NewValue;

                Debug.WriteLine("Memory:" + DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1024 / 1024);

                if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool || !uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                {
                    image.Source = PhoneAppVKContest.ImageUtils.getJpegImage(uri.OriginalString);
                }
                else
                {
                    PhoneAppVKContest.downloadImage di = new PhoneAppVKContest.downloadImage(0, uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    di.destinationImage = image;
                    di.FileCompleteEvent += new PhoneAppVKContest.downloadImage.FileCompleteHandler(di_FileCompleteEvent);
                    di.Download();
                }
            }
        }

        static void di_FileCompleteEvent(object sender)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Download success!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating webClient request for each image, then a conflict may arise when the webClient is bombarded with all the requests. You need to order the requests sequentially via a queue. If the image in the queue's first element is already in the cache or IS, link it, else check if webclient is busy or not. If busy then send it to the end of the queue. And check for the next image. If its not busy, submit a downloading request. This is the method which I have followed. You might also consider binding the Imagesource for each image inorder to prevent auto reloading on page reload or due to problem in scroll cache. I hope this answer helps you.